# Installing Esri FGDB API with GDAL (Python 3.5)

Tags: gdal, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase-api, python-3

I've recently migrated to ArcGIS Pro 1.4 and have had no problems moving from Python 2.7 to 3.5 - except one.  I try to use gdal/ogr when I can in order to share scripts easily with those who do not have an Arc license available.  In the 2.7 version, I could easily obtain support for read/write of Esri file geodatabases by placing the `FileGDBAPI.dll` into

`Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins`

However, with ArcGIS Pro (Python 3.5) when I installed the gdal (2.1.3) wheel (obtained from Christoph Gohlke's site at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs), there is no `gdalplugins` folder.  I only have the following structure:

`C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\osgeo`

Under this, I have:

`\__pycache__`
`\data`
`\include`
`\lib`
`\scripts`

There are only 2 .dll files in the entire structure; `gdal201.dll` and `geos_c.dll`.

Could someone tell me where the file geodatabase drivers reside, and if adding Esri's `FileGDBAPI.dll` to the same directory is all that's needed to get things working?

**My limitations are:** Windows 7 64-bit, I need to be able to deal with pre-compiled binaries, I do not have a compiler available to me or full administrative rights on the machine.

Comment: What happened when you tried "adding Esri's FileGDBAPI.dll to the same directory"?

Comment: @PolyGeo nothing. Doesn't do anything.  ogrinfo reveals no r/w support for Esri FGDB.  I ended up simply rolling back to Python 2.7 for compatibility.